# Accept a name in Text Box, Print it when someone click on Print Button

Tags: vb6

I have a TextBox in VB and a Command Button. I want to print the string upon clicking on command button. 
I am using the following code, please tell what I am doing wrong:-

```
Dim name As String 
name = Val(Text1.Text) 
MsgBox ("Welcome" & Str(name))
```

When I input a string in Textbox and click on command button, result is:

```
Welcome 0
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the sheet the textbox is in? E.g. Sheets(1).TextBox1.Text. Don't use Val as it specifies a number. You want a string, not a number

Comment: VBA is the language of Office and VB6. However you don't tag VB6 as VBA as they have different forms packages. VBScript is pasteable into VBA/VB6, but rarely the other way. SO TWO of your tags are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave out the `val()` around your `Text1.Text`, `val()` returns the numbers up to the first symbol it can't recognize as a number used in a String. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function). I guess you used a `0` in your string in the TextField or no number at all, both would return `0`.

Additionally, it is unnecessary to cast your `String name` to a `String` since it is already a `String` so you can also leave out the `Str()`.

Comment: The documentation you linked is VBA but the OP hasn’t clarified whether they’re using VB, VBA (inside an host application, Excel, Word etc).

Answer (score -1):

So you declared a string varaible `name`which you want to fill with the text from the `Text1`box. So you need to spare the `val(...)`part.
Second, as `name`already represents a string, leave out the `str`in the message box:

```
name = Text1.Text
MsgBox ("Welcome " & name)
```

Comment: Please, add some context around your code snippets, explaining why the OP has the problem he/she is facing and how your code solves that given problem

Answer (score -1):

The `val` function returns the numeric representation of its argument, otherwise it returns "0". It's a bit hard these days to find the official VB6 documentation, but you may want to check: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/VB6_Command_Reference#Val

So, in your example, if you enter any number in the `Text1` textbox control, you will see it in your message box. If you enter any text, you will get "Welcome 0", as you do now. Therefore, you have to remove the `val` function from your code, like:

```
Dim name As String 
name = Text1.Text
MsgBox ("Welcome " & name)
```

maybe even simplifying it to:

```
MsgBox("Welcome " & Text1.Text)
```